# Passing A model to a ViewModel using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I'm working on a ASP.NET core project. I want to map a model to a viewmodel using Automapper but there is a problem which is described below
This is  ***MyRepository***

```
 public class MyRepository
 {
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Cars>> GetAllCarsAsync()
    {
        return await _RepositoryContext.Set<Cars>().ToListAsync();
    }
 }
```

And this is ***MyController***

```
 public class MyController: Controller
 {
    [HttpGET]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
      {
          var car = await _MyRepository.GetAllCarTypesAsync();
          var model = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarsVM>>(car);
          return View(model);
      }
 }
```

And finally this is my View

```
@model  DataLayers.Models.ViewModels.CarsVM

<form " asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create">
  <label class="label" asp-for="Carname"></label>
  <input class="input" type="text" asp-for="Carname">
  <select>
     <option> A carType </option>
     <option>A carType </option>
  </select>
</from>
```

The problem is in my controller. var car returns IEnumerable and then we map the result to CarsVM. when i pass the  model to view, it expects  CarsVM not IEnumerable of CarsVM. how can I covert them? And if it's now possible to convert them so what shall i do? how can I pass my data to view?

Comment: You can never take an Enumerable of anything and assign that to a non-enumerable container.

Comment: @ErikPhilips So what is the solution? what shall i do?? shall I make a new repository??

Comment: I have NO IDEA. You haven't explain what you're trying to do, just whats not working.  What's your view look like?  DO you want all cars or 1 car?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Actually this view is a create view. In that view admins can add a car. Admins are also able to select carType from a dropdown list which gets its data from database. And id u need more information just tell me which part is needed i will add it.

Comment: What is `CarsVM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest updating the automapper line to convert to a List instead of the IEnumerable interface so that you can ensure the view model is materialized within the controller. It is obvious looking at the repository code but not if you can only see the repository returning an IEnumerable.

The main changes below are to ensure that AutoMapper maps to a list of view model objects and that the view is receiving a model made up of a list of those view model objects. I have assumed that the CarsVM object is a viewmodel instance of a single Cars object.

**Repository**

```
public class MyRepository
{
    public async Task<List<Cars>> GetAllCarsAsync()
    {
        return await _RepositoryContext.Set<Cars>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    [HttpGET]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var car = await _MyRepository.GetAllCarTypesAsync();
        var model = _mapper.Map<List<CarsVM>>(car);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model List<DataLayers.Models.ViewModels.CarsVM>
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create">
    <label class="label" asp-for="Carname"></label>
    <input class="input" type="text" asp-for="Carname">
    <select>
       <option> A carType </option>
       <option>A carType </option>
    </select>
</from>
```